# Where Bitcoin using ECDSA and ECDH

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin, ecdsa

```
1.var hash = crypto.randomBytes(32);
2.var publickey = ecdh.setPrivateKey(hash,'hex').getPublicKey('hex');
then sha256 => ripemd160 => encode... => address
```

I know how the bitcoin address generated,but seems it just using ECDH to generate bitcoin address,but I saw lots of talk says it using ECDSA,I want to know where bitcoin using ECDSA and how bitcoin using cryptography to verify transaction and which crypto function using for signing transaction.
Thanks.

Comment: Try [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) but read their tutorial first, this may be too broad over there as well.

Comment: Do the stackexchange link you provide has tutorial for technical detail? never heard about it

Comment: Sorry, meant the [tour](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: After I read into bitcoin source code I roughly know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin doesn't use ECDSA for its address generation, save from the fact that you can use the public key of the ECDSA to generate a Bitcoin address.  Where the Elliptic curve is really used is in signing the transaction.

First you create a raw transaction with all the correct fields in, including the ScriptPubKey and then convert that to list of bytes.  You then take the SHA256 of the transaction bytes and then SHA256 the result of the SHA256.  This is the message digest and this is what you need to sign with the ECDSA private key to generate the SigScript.  The SigScript however contains more than just the signed digest.  First comes a digest length + 1 for the SIGHASH_CODE, then comes the signature itself, followed by sig hash code, then a length for the public key and finally the public key itself. Once you've concatenated all of these, that's your SigScript that needs to be inserted into the transaction.  Obviously the entire SigScript is prefixed with a size, just like the SigPubKey.  Lastly insert the size and the result and now you have a signed transaction you can broadcast.

Comment: Usually it’s called a scriptSig